# How to use OData Authentication (OData Client V7)?

Tags: c#, authentication, odata, kerberos, odata-v4

How can I use **Kerberos** / NTLM authentication (*like in the HttpClient*) within the OData Client from Microsoft (`Microsoft.OData.Client`)?

I am using the package `Microsoft.OData.Client 7.9.0` and I am trying to connect to a OData endpoint with https and authentication enabled. However I am not able to retrieve any data, instead this exception is thrown:

```
Microsoft.OData.Edm.Csdl.EdmParseException: "Encountered the following errors when parsing the CSDL document: 
XmlError : Root element is missing. : (0, 0)"
```

It seems that the context could not find the requested resource because of a lack of permissions. This is the referencial implementation:

```
// Simple data class
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

// OData service context
public class Container : DataServiceContext
{
    public DataServiceQuery<Person> People { get; }

    public Container(Uri serviceRoot) : base(serviceRoot)
    {
        People = base.CreateQuery<Person>(nameof(People));

        // This is not working ...
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", @"p@ssw0rd!");
    }
}
```

---

```
Container context = new Container(new Uri("https://targetservice.dev/ODataV4/$metadata"));
var result = context.People.Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<Person>;
```

Providing credentials to the `Credentials` property does not seem to have any effect here.

Comment: You don't have to use code for this - you only need to enable Windows authentication on the IIS site/web application. If you use ASP.NET Core and Kestel, you need to enable Windows authentication in `Startup.cs`. The [OData section at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/basic-auth) makes this clear: `The fact is that using OData is orthogonal to authentication and authorization. That is to say, you may secure an OData API in any way you can secure a generic RESTful API. We write this post to demonstrate it.`.

Comment: To make an HTTP call using Windows auth all you have to do is either nothing and let classes use the current user's identity, or set the `Credential` property of either the container or HttpClientHandler, if you want to use an external HttpClient instance. If you use .NET Core, both can be handles in the DI configuration. Why not use `context.Credentials=CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` from the start?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no direct influence on the web service and can therefore not make any changes to the type of authentication but windows authentication is enabled by default though. This is a Dynamics 365 Business Central, which provides the OData endpoint. I've already tested `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` - it didn't work.

Comment: On the contrary -the code in the answer you posted sets `Credential` to `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` or a custom credential. `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` will fail only if the current user *isn't* allowed to connect. In a web application the current user is the service/app pool account unless impersonation is used

Comment: On the other hand `CheckCertificateRevocationList = true` is a very strong smell. There shouldn't be any certificate issues in a Windows domain. All machines in the domain trust the domain controller as a Certificate Authority. Are you executing this code on a non-Domain machine? In that case, the current user will *not* be an authenticated domain use and the service will deny access

Answer (score 1):

Set the credentials from the *outside*, before using the container for the first time. After all, you don't want to modify your `Container` every time the credentials change. Nor do you want to hard-code into the `Container` the mechanism you use to retrieve those credentials.

Assuming both the server and client are in the same domain, one can connect using Windows authentication as the current user, with [CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials?view=net-5.0)

```
var uri=new Uri("https://targetservice.dev/ODataV4/$metadata");
Container context = new Container(uri){
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
};
var result = context.People.Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<Person>;
```

If you want to connect from a non-Domain machine or use a different account, you'll have to create a `NetworkCredential` instance :

```
var credential = new NetworkCredential("MyDomain","UserName","Password");

Container context = new Container(uri){
    Credentials = credential
};
```

The main advantage of Windows authentication is that you *don't* need to explicitly specify the credentials. Any remote calls will be made using the current account. This way there's no password to store, change or leak. This of course assumes that both the client and server are in the same Windows domain, otherwise the client account won't be recognized by the server.

**Wrong URL**

The exception snippet complains about the server's response, not failed authentication. `XmlError : Root element is missing. : (0, 0)` means that the response was *not* an XML document. It's not an error response either. If the server had responded with a 4xx or 5xx status, a different exception would be thrown.

The service URL is wrong and *shouldn't* contain the `$metadata` suffix. As the constructor name says `DataServiceContext(Uri serviceRoot)` the URL should be the service's root. That URL is stored in the `BaseUriResolver` property:

```
internal DataServiceContext(Uri serviceRoot, ODataProtocolVersion maxProtocolVersion, ClientEdmModel model)
{
     Debug.Assert(model != null, "model != null");
   this.model = model;

   this.baseUriResolver = UriResolver.CreateFromBaseUri(serviceRoot, ServiceRootParameterName);
```

The metadata URL is created by the `GetMetadataUri` method whose code is:

```
public virtual Uri GetMetadataUri()
{
    // TODO: resolve the location of the metadata endpoint for the service by using an HTTP OPTIONS request
    Uri metadataUri = UriUtil.CreateUri(UriUtil.UriToString(
        this.BaseUriResolver.GetBaseUriWithSlash()) + 
        XmlConstants.UriMetadataSegment, 
        UriKind.Absolute);
    return metadataUri;
}
```

Using `https://targetservice.dev/ODataV4/$metadata` as the service URL would result in an invalid `https://targetservice.dev/ODataV4/$metadata/$metadata` metadata URL

To troubleshoot such errors, Fiddler or another debugging proxy can be used to intercept HTTP calls and inspect what gets sent and what is actually returned by the server.

Comment: Thank you. But `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` seems not to work. I get the exception mentioned in the OP. It has something to do with the line `Format.LoadServiceModel = () => RequestModel();` in my answer. The machine/account are within the Windows domain and if I load the `EdmModel` from a file it's working like in my answer. How should I then load the EdmModel if not per http request?

Comment: But your code does use `Credentials` with an `HttpRequest`. OData clients don't have to store the metadata files first - if that was the case, people would have noticed and complained 10 years ago when OData was released. The error you got is because the *server* returned an HTML page instead of metadata or an 401 or 403 error, probably redirecting you to a login or custom error page. You didn't post the full exception so one can't guess where the error was thrown, or in response to what call.

Comment: @PhilippApe it's quite possible the URL is wrong. The client URL doesn't include the `$metadata` suffix. That's appended when the client needs to actually load metadata. Use Fiddler or another debugging proxy to check what the server returns

Comment: @PhilippApe according to the source code the URL you used would result in a call to `https://targetservice.dev/ODataV4/$metadata/$metadata`, not `https://targetservice.dev/ODataV4/$metadata/`

Comment: Thank you a lot. But the exception message keeps the same even if I remove `$metadata`. After some debugging with fiddler I saw that the requested resource uri was correct (`https://targetservice.dev/ODataV4/$metadata/`) but there was an 401 unauthorized status returned by the server - the exception kept the same. In a browser/Postman I am able to get the metadata without any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of research and testing, I managed to get this working. Indeed the requested resource (**CSDL**) could not be requested because of a **lack of permissions**. But the CSDL can be requested using a **HttpClient** initially, which takes the supplied credentials into account:

```
public class Container : DataServiceContext
{

    public override ICredentials Credentials { get => base.Credentials; set => throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    public bool UseDefaultCredentials { get; }

    public DataServiceQuery<Person> People { get; }

    private static IEdmModel? ParsedModel;

    public Container(Uri serviceRoot, ICredentials? credentials = null, bool useDefaultCredentials = false) : base(serviceRoot)
    {
        if (serviceRoot is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceRoot));
        base.Credentials = useDefaultCredentials ? credentials ?? CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials : credentials;
        UseDefaultCredentials = useDefaultCredentials;

        People = base.CreateQuery<Person>(nameof(People));

        // It is required to load the service model initially.
        Format.LoadServiceModel = () => RequestModel();
        Format.UseJson();
    }

    // This method requets the service model directly from the OData endpoint via HttpClient.
    // It also uses the supplied credentials.
    private IEdmModel RequestModel()
    {
        if (ParsedModel is not null) return ParsedModel;

        // Create http client (+ handler) populated with credentials.
        using HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new()
        {
            Credentials = UseDefaultCredentials ? CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials : Credentials,
            CheckCertificateRevocationList = true
        };

        using HttpClient httpClient = new(clientHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new UriBuilder()
            {
                Scheme = BaseUri.Scheme,
                Host = BaseUri.Host,
                Port = BaseUri.Port
            }.Uri
        };

        // Process the response stream via XmlReader and CsdlReader.
        using var responseStream = httpClient.GetStreamAsync(
            new Uri(Path.Combine(BaseUri.AbsolutePath, "$metadata"), UriKind.Relative))
            .ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        using var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream);

        if (!CsdlReader.TryParse(xmlReader, out var model, out var errors))
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessages = new();
            foreach (var error in errors) errorMessages.Append(error.ErrorMessage).Append("; ");
            throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessages.ToString());
        }

        // Return and cache the parsed model.
        return ParsedModel = model;
    }
}
```

By then it can be used the following:

```
Container context = new Container(new Uri("https://targetservice.dev/ODataV4/"), useDefaultCredentials: true);
```

**UPDATE**

This seems to be a bug in the implementation not forwarding credential information to the metadata request. The following stacktrace shows the call of the `LoadServiceModelFromNetwork` method:

```
at Microsoft.OData.Edm.Csdl.CsdlReader.Parse(XmlReader reader)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientFormat.LoadServiceModelFromNetwork()
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientFormat.get_ServiceModel()
at Microsoft.OData.Client.RequestInfo..ctor(DataServiceContext context)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.CreateExecuteResult(Object source, DataServiceContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, String method)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
```

The current implementation within the package is the following:

```
internal IEdmModel LoadServiceModelFromNetwork()
{
    DataServiceClientRequestMessage httpRequest;
    BuildingRequestEventArgs requestEventArgs = null;

    // test hook for injecting a network request to use instead of the default
    if (InjectMetadataHttpNetworkRequest != null)
        // ...
    else
    {
        // ...
        httpRequest = new HttpClientRequestMessage(args);
    }

    // ...

    Task<IODataResponseMessage> asyncResponse =
        Task<IODataResponseMessage>.Factory.FromAsync(httpRequest.BeginGetResponse, httpRequest.EndGetResponse,
            httpRequest);
    IODataResponseMessage response = asyncResponse.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    // ...

    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetStream()))
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(streamReader))
    {
        return CsdlReader.Parse(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

As it turns out the `httpRequest` variable here is responsible for handling the actual response. The constructor is implemented as follows:

```
public HttpClientRequestMessage(DataServiceClientRequestMessageArgs args) 
    : base(args.ActualMethod)
{
    _messageStream = new MemoryStream();
    _handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    _client = new HttpClient(_handler, disposeHandler: true);
    _contentHeaderValueCache = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    _effectiveHttpMethod = args.Method;
    _requestUrl = args.RequestUri;
    _requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(this.ActualMethod), _requestUrl);

    // Now set the headers.
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValue in args.Headers)
    {
            this.SetHeader(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
    }
}
```

Neither the credentials nor the boolean `UseDefaultCredentials` is forwarded to the `HttpClientHandler`. But the `args` provide this information.
Also the credentials are not set after construction and the response is not checked for an invalid status code so that it ends up in this strange behavior.

Comment: You don't need *any* of this. You actually don't need anything. Just enable Windows authentication for the project,  if not for the IIS site. The OData documentation is *very* clear that OData itself neither handles nor affects authentication